# Having my side bar open and close when in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css

Now I have the HTML, CSS and JS for it to work but when I test it, it doesn't work.

What I am trying to achieve is that the sidebar can be opened and closed upon pressing when in mobile view.

**HTML**

```
        <div id="tm-sidebar" class="tm-sidebar">
        <nav class="tm-nav">
            <button id="navbar-toggler" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <div>
                <div class="tm-brand-box">
                    <img src="img/37.png" width="100%" height="180" alt="Logo">
                </div>
                <ul id="tm-main-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#home" class="nav-link current">
                            <div class="triangle-right"></div>
                            <i class="fas fa-home nav-icon"></i>
                            Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#about" class="nav-link">
                            <div class="triangle-right"></div>
                            <i class="fas fa-images nav-icon"></i>
                            About
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#afc" class="nav-link">
                            <div class="triangle-right"></div>
                            <i class="fas fa-envelope nav-icon"></i>
                            Armed Forces
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">
                            <div class="triangle-right"></div>
                            <i class="fas fa-envelope nav-icon"></i>
                            Contact
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="https://cp.dcsit.co.uk/" class="nav-link external" target="_new" rel="sponsored">
                            <div class="triangle-right"></div>
                            <i class="fas fa-external-link-alt nav-icon"></i>
                            Packages
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
    var navbarToggler = document.getElementById("navbar-toggler");
var mainNav = document.getElementById("tm-main-nav");

function toggleNavbar() {
    mainNav.classList.toggle("show");
}

navbarToggler.addEventListener("click", toggleNavbar);

// Check if the device width is less than or equal to 768px (typical mobile device width)
function checkDeviceWidth() {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
        navbarToggler.style.display = "block";
        mainNav.classList.remove("show"); // Start with the navbar closed
    } else {
        navbarToggler.style.display = "none";
        mainNav.classList.remove("show");
    }
}

// Check the device width on page load and when the window is resized
window.addEventListener("load", checkDeviceWidth);
window.addEventListener("resize", checkDeviceWidth);
```

**CSS**

```
.show {
display: block !important;
}
```

The button displays on the phone but does not do anything when clicked.
Thank you in anticipation for your help.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, the button show on small screen, that works.
Click on it add show in main nav, that works too.

Check you init status.
big screen: main nav should be visible, button hidden
small screen: main nav hidden, button visible

```js
var navbarToggler = document.getElementById("navbar-toggler");
var mainNav = document.getElementById("tm-main-nav");

function toggleNavbar() {
  mainNav.classList.toggle("hide");
}

navbarToggler.addEventListener("click", toggleNavbar);

// Check if the device width is less than or equal to 768px (typical mobile device width)
function checkDeviceWidth() {
  if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
    navbarToggler.classList.remove("hide");
    mainNav.classList.add("hide"); // Start with the navbar closed
  } else {
    navbarToggler.classList.add("hide");
    mainNav.classList.remove("hide");
  }
}

// Check the device width on page load and when the window is resized
window.addEventListener("load", checkDeviceWidth);
window.addEventListener("resize", checkDeviceWidth);
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none !important;
}

.show {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="tm-sidebar" class="tm-sidebar">
  <nav class="tm-nav">
    <button id="navbar-toggler" class="navbar-toggler hide" type="button" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
    <div>
      <div class="tm-brand-box">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/180" width="100%" height="180" alt="Logo">
      </div>
      <ul id="tm-main-nav" class="hide">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#home" class="nav-link current">
            <div class="triangle-right"></div>
            <i class="fas fa-home nav-icon"></i> Home
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#about" class="nav-link">
            <div class="triangle-right"></div>
            <i class="fas fa-images nav-icon"></i> About
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#afc" class="nav-link">
            <div class="triangle-right"></div>
            <i class="fas fa-envelope nav-icon"></i> Armed Forces
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">
            <div class="triangle-right"></div>
            <i class="fas fa-envelope nav-icon"></i> Contact
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="https://cp.dcsit.co.uk/" class="nav-link external" target="_new" rel="sponsored">
            <div class="triangle-right"></div>
            <i class="fas fa-external-link-alt nav-icon"></i> Packages
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

By the way, check resize observer, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver, it's vers useful when dealing screen size